# Why make file not able to get the source file from specific src directory?

Tags: linux, makefile

I am very new in linux and learning makefile

Following is my directory structure

```
calculator
|
|---src
     |--Calc
          (multiply.cpp sum.cpp)
     |-- main.cpp
     |-- Makefile 
|---lib
```

Makefile

```
LIB_PATH=./../lib
HEAD_PATH=./../head
SRC_DIR=./calc

all: main

main: main.o calc.a
        g++ main.o -L$(LIB_PATH) -l:calc.a
main.o: main.cpp
        g++ -c -I$(HEAD_PATH) main.cpp
calc.a: Multiply.o Sum.o
        ar -rcs $(LIB_PATH)/calc.a Multiply.o Sum.o
Multiply.o: Multiply.cpp
        g++ -c -I$(HEAD_PATH) $(SRC_DIR)/Multiply.cpp
Sum.o: Sum.cpp
        g++ -c -I$(HEAD_PATH) $(SRC_DIR)/Sum.cpp
```

My current directory is src
I am running make command on command line.
and getting error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `Multiply.cpp', needed by `Multiply.o'.  Stop.
```

if I put all source file inside src instead of calc folder everything working fine.
I tried and exectued each and every line written makefile on command prompt it is working fine there

How can I tell that pick the src from calc folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the path in the rule:

```
Multiply.o: $(SRC_DIR)/Multiply.cpp
```

Alternatively, set [`VPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html) to `SRC_DIR`:

```
VPATH = $(SRC_DIR)
```

Oh, and the filesystem is not case-insensitive. If the output from `tree` above is copy-pasted, you'll have to say `multiply.cpp` instead of `Multiply.cpp`, and the same for `Sum.cpp`/`sum.cpp` and the `.o` files.